# Node.js is not accessible from external IPs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 Server where i have configured the node js server, it is not accessible from the outside by the public dns but it is accessible by the same instance(localhost). Any help will be much appreciated.

**Server Code :**

```
var my_http = require("http");
my_http.createServer(function(request,response){
    console.log("Request Recieved : "+request.url);
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Server is UP \n"); 
}).listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
console.log("Server is Running on Port 3000");
```

**netstat output**

```
netstat -tupln | grep :3000  
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:3000     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN   11706/node
```

**curl output**

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3000                =>     Server is UP 
curl http://localhost:3000                =>     Server is UP 
curl http://{PRIVATE_IP}:3000             =>     Server is UP 
curl http://{PUBLIC_DNS}:3000             =>     curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Have you opened port 3000 in your security group?

Comment: Yes port 80, 22, 3000, 3001 are open

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like a security group issue.

In your EC2 control panel, locate your instance and scroll all the way to the right. There is a Security Group column, and if you haven't changed the default name your security group will be called something like "launch-wizard-1".

Click it, and that opens a filtered list of security groups (there will probably be just one entry in the list).

Right-click it and select Edit Inbound Rules.

Add a rule that says:

```
Type: HTTP
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 3000
Source: Anywwhere
```

Save and it should work.